# How to use undetected-chromedriver and google-chrome in a Python script running in a Debian instance?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm testing undetected-chrome driver v2 but it doesn't work for me. I have the following ouput:

```
[2021-09-09 10:51:22,992] [easyprocess] [DEBUG] command: ['Xvfb', '-help']
[2021-09-09 10:51:22,998] [easyprocess] [DEBUG] process was started (pid=18555)
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,003] [easyprocess] [DEBUG] process has ended, return code=0
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,004] [pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay] [DEBUG] command: ['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '1280x1024x24', '-displayfd', '5']
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,082] [pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay] [DEBUG] set $DISPLAY=:1
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,083] [root] [INFO] Loading UNDETECTED chromedriver (headless,even)...
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,085] [undetected_chromedriver.patcher] [DEBUG] getting release number from /LATEST_RELEASE
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,215] [undetected_chromedriver.patcher] [DEBUG] downloading from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/92.0.4515.107/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,492] [undetected_chromedriver.patcher] [DEBUG] unzipping /tmp/tmp8h9nukgw
[2021-09-09 10:51:23,626] [undetected_chromedriver.patcher] [INFO] patching driver executable /usr/bin/chromedriver
[2021-09-09 10:51:24,825] [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] [DEBUG] POST http://127.0.0.1:36987/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "any", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "binary": "/bin/google-chrome", "args": ["--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic", "--remote-debugging-host=127.0.0.1", "--remote-debugging-port=60625", "--user-data-dir=/opt/testing/data/temp", "--lang=en-GB", "--log-level=0"], "debuggerAddress": "127.0.0.1:60625"}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "chrome", "version": "", "platform": "ANY", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "binary": "/bin/google-chrome", "args": ["--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic", "--remote-debugging-host=127.0.0.1", "--remote-debugging-port=60625", "--user-data-dir=/opt/testing/data/temp", "--lang=en-GB", "--log-level=0"], "debuggerAddress": "127.0.0.1:60625"}}}
[2021-09-09 10:51:24,828] [urllib3.connectionpool] [DEBUG] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:36987
[2021-09-09 10:52:24,896] [urllib3.connectionpool] [DEBUG] http://127.0.0.1:36987 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 767
[2021-09-09 10:52:24,897] [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] [DEBUG] Finished Request
[2021-09-09 10:52:24,898] [root] [ERROR] Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:60625
from chrome not reachable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/testing/test_undetected_chromedriver.py", line 117, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/v2.py", line 291, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/v2.py", line 553, in start_session
    super().start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/testing/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:60625
from chrome not reachable

[2021-09-09 10:52:24,904] [pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay] [DEBUG] set $DISPLAY=:0.0
[2021-09-09 10:52:24,911] [pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay] [DEBUG] stdout=b''
[2021-09-09 10:52:24,911] [pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay] [DEBUG] stderr=b'_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed\n_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running\n'
```

I have tested it in different machines, all Debian 10 instances. The version of installed chrome is 93.0.4577.63 and Chromedriver version is 93.0.4577.15.

The lines of code of my python script involved are:

```py
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.user_data_dir = '/opt/testing/data/temp/'
options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

Other versions of interest:

- undetected-chromedriver 3.0.2
- Python 3.9

Thank you in advance to anyone who could help me.

Comment: I also have checked it with the latest version of undected-chromedriver, 3.0.3.

Comment: Try starting chromedriver manually with specified port and then connect to it